# Every even integer $n>2$ is a semiprime or sum of two semiprime numbers.

Tags: summation, prime-numbers

**Progress**:

I was wondering as to how this statement can be proved/disproved, though it may seem a bit trivial.

I would really appreciate any opinion or insight as well.

Regards

Comment: This sounds very nontrivial. Look up Chen's theorem.

Comment: Even semiprimes have essentially the same frequency as primes. Which version (in title or in body) are you asking about?

Comment: The stronger version is certainly not true: it says that every integer $n>1$ is either prime or the sum of two primes; for a counterexample it suffices to take odd $n$ such that neither $n$ and $n-2$ are prime, e.g. $27$.

Comment: @barto $n$ is supposed to be even, so I think you mean $2\cdot 27$.

Comment: @Wojowu:  I'm confused because in your very next message you point out the restriction to "even" semiprimes.   So, are we on the same page?

Comment: @hardmath Sorry, I didn't notice your comment was about even semiprimes. I see your point now.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @hardmath

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To summarize some of what I think the Comments are trying to say falsifies the "strong" version, let $n$ be any odd composite number.  Then $2n$ is not an "even semiprime" (since $n$ is not prime).

But if $2n$ were the sum of two even semiprimes, we should have $n$ as a sum of two primes.  Since this is possible only if $n-2$ is prime, it is pretty easy to find counterexamples. As barto and Wojowu point out, $n=27$ is an odd composite with $n-2$ also composite, so we cannot write $2n= 54$ as a sum of two even semiprimes.  There are indeed infinitely many such counterexamples, so the strong version fails despite adding a caveat for "all sufficiently large integers".

On the other hand the weak version might hold for all sufficiently large integers.  For example, the value $54$, despite not being "an even semiprime", can be expressed as the sum of two semiprimes:

$$ 54 = 15 + 39 = 3\cdot 5 + 3\cdot 13 $$

If $2n$ is not an even semiprime, then $n$ must be a composite. Suppose that $p$ is a prime factor of $n$, and that $n = pm$ for $m \gt 1$.  Applying [Goldbach's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldbach%27s_conjecture) to $2m$ would give it as a sum of a pair of primes:

$$ 2m = q_1 + q_2 $$

and give $2n = 2pm = p q_1 + p q_2$ as a sum of a pair of *semiprimes*.

Therefore the "weak" version shown in the Question's title is implied by Goldbach's conjecture.

Comment: What if m is also prime?!